# Python 3 Include Custom File with Variables

Tags: python, variables, printing

How to include external config file with variables and use them in python script ?

Python Variables File: (auth.txt)

```
Username = 'username_here'
Password = 'password_here'
```

Python Script (test.py)

```
print('Username:', Username)
print('Password:', Password)
```

Comment: Rename `auth.txt` to `auth.py` and `import` it.

Comment: Actually I got it with renaming to auth.py then using from auth import * Is there any other ways to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it by using;

auth.py

```
# Python Variables
USR = 'user_here'
PWD = 'pass_here'
```

test.py

```
#!/bin/python -B
from auth import *
print('Username:', USR)
print('Password:', PWD)
```

Answer (score 2):

configparser will let you treat it like a dictionary:

config.txt

```
[DEFAULT]
USR = user_here
PWD = pass_here
```

auth.py:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('./config.txt')
print(config['DEFAULT']['USR'])
print(config['DEFAULT']['PWD'])
```

yields:

```
user_here
pass_here
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution. There are others, e.g. `xml.etree.ElementTree` if you need to use an XML file, but for your purposes `configparser` does everything you want in a familiar syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer my own answer instead. I don't like using ini style config especially if it requires additional module. But thanks.